# Play Framework Delete request

Tags: javascript, html, playframework

Hope someone can help me, I am trying to get a delete request to work in play framework. From my html page I have a button which is then using an ajax statement but at the moment I am getting an cannot read property 'addeventlistener' of null error. I am new to all this and was following a tutorial but this used the onclick method which I am now trying to get past. Thank You

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click" ,sendDeleteRequest);

function sendDeleteRequest(url, rUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "DELETE",
        success: function () {
            window.location = rUrl;
            },
        error: function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

and my html

```
 <button class ="btn btn-danger" id="myBtn('@routes.BooksController.destroy(book.id)',
    '@routes.HomeController.index()'
    )" >Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing your `id` attribute and other attributes.

Use `data-` attributes to store your routes instead :

```
<button class ="btn btn-danger" 
  id="myBtn" 
  data-url="@routes.BooksController.destroy(book.id)" 
  data-redirect-url="@routes.HomeController.index()" 
>Delete</button>
```

And use them using `that.getAttribute()` in Javascript :

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click" ,sendDeleteRequest);

function sendDeleteRequest() {
    let that = this;
    $.ajax({
        url: that.getAttribute('data-url'), //Here
        method: "DELETE",
        success: function () {
            window.location = that.getAttribute('data-redirect-url'); //Here
        },
        error: function() {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is working but in the console I am getting a message "uncaught typeerror: cannot ready property 'addeventlistener' of null. Is this something i need to be concerned with?

Comment: You have to make sure your button has the ID `myBtn`, else it won't work.

Comment: yes I have that, the second line in the new html code

Comment: Well, you should check where your error comes from, if it comes from the Javascript in my answer, it means your Javascript is getting executed before your button has been inserted in the page. So try moving the script at the end of the `body`.